# How to retrieve document ID from faunaDb query

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, faunadb

I have this array

```
[ Ref(Collection("twitch_users"), "280881231730573837") ]
```

And i wish to retrive the string of numbers and use them for another function in my code, however I'm unsure how I can do this as I'm used to doing something like `data.info[0]` but the object doesn't have a name and I'm not sure how to achieve something like that without using a name.

This may be a little hard to reproduce as the data is being retrieved from an external database but i'll do my best to provide whats needed

```
// These first two lines return
// [ Ref(Collection("twitch_users"), "280881231730573837") ]
// Please note Ref() is from the FaunaDB API and not a function in my code



var queryuserInfo = fauna.paginate(q.Match(q.Index("users.allInfo"), tags.username));
queryuserInfo.each(function (page) { userInfo = page });
```

I then console.log

```
console.log(userInfo[0])
```

Comment: What does Ref() returns?

Comment: Are you just looking for `data[1]`?

Comment: @Bergi thought so myself, but notice the "2808.." is actually the second param to the Ref() function.

Comment: @Bergi that's what I thought the answer was as well, unfortunately ```data[1]``` returns undefined

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka oops, you're right. In that case, the question is not answerable without further details about what `Ref` is.

Comment: @Adsnipers Please provide a [mcve] that shows how the array is constructed

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka do you mean just ```console.log(Ref)``` ?

Comment: Try console.log(Ref(Collection("twitch_users"), "280881231730573837").id);
What does it give?

Comment: I would recommend mentioning in the question itself this is the `Ref()` of FaunaDB API.

Comment: I've made some edits to my initial question to help provide what you would need to reproduce my question

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir ```queryuserInfo.each```is not async, however where i am logging / trying to retrieve the info IS async.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the Ref ID generated by [FaunaDB](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/ref?lang=javascript). You can use the `id` attribute to retrieve the ID.

```
console.log(userInfo[0].id)
```

Comment: YAAAAS, thank you so much. I almost pulled an allnighter figuring this one out haha

Comment: I'm glad this helped you :)